# Selective compilation of source code

Tags: c, optimization

I am working on a C project which is quite large and consists of multiple source files. I have written a script to find out all the functions in this code that are never used (Only defined once but never used elsewhere). Now I want to compile my code without including these functions. Is there any direct way to exclude certain functions from a compilation?

I understand that I can use #ifdef/#endif for each of these functions and leave them out, but inserting these at the right location using a script is turning out to be really challenging, hence the question.

PS: I have already used all compiler/linker optimizations and this exercise is supposed to be beyond those (as no optimization has been successful in removing 100% dead code and I dont expect it to). So I am not really looking for answers in that area.

Comment: Can't you write a mini-parser that removes them from the source files before feeding them to the compiler?

Comment: @Tudor: Yes, that would be similar in approach to what I mentioned in paragraph 2 above i.e removing functions will have a same level of difficulty as adding a #ifdef at the beginning of a function and a #endif at the end, which I wan to avoid unless there is no easier way out.
(Pardon my laziness?)

Comment: If they are never called they're probably not compiled? Unless it's a DLL

Comment: @James: I wish that was the case! But surprisingly compiler optimizations have failed to remove 100% dead code in my case...

Comment: @Scranton this is highly compiler dependent. For many (most?) compilers, dead code is removed at the object level, meaning if one function in the source file is used, the entire object is retained.

Comment: @mah: I realize that...Hence the attempt to move beyond compiler optimizations to do what I am doing...

Comment: @Scranton: How did you find out if dead code is completely removed? I am unfamiliar in this area, so I ask.

Comment: @Bhaskar: The symbol table I obtain from the object file, still contains functions which I know arent being used anywhere.

Comment: You might want to explore Clang to analyze and tweak C(++) source code. [Relevant article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/08/basic-source-to-source-transformation-with-clang/).